# subsetting a dataframe based on matching row values across multiple columns

Tags: r, match, subset

I can't seem to find the answer to what I need anywhere, so apologies if this is a duplicate.

Suppose I have the following `df`:

```
a    b    c    d  
1    2    3    4  
2    1    2    3  
1    2    4    4
```

I want to subset my df so that matching rows based on the "a", "b", and "d" columns are returned in a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `duplicated` on the subset of the columns to return a logical `vector` to filter the rows

```
df[duplicated(df[c('a', 'b', 'd')])|duplicated(df[c('a', 'b', 'd')], 
                fromLast = TRUE),]
#  a b c d
#1 1 2 3 4
#3 1 2 4 4
```

---

It can also be done with a group by operation and `filter` those groups that have more than 1 row

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(a, b, d) %>%
   filter(n() > 1)
```

with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N > 1], by = .(a, b, d)]
```